# Extract a specific-length number from a string javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, inline

First shot at javascript. I need to extract a song id from a full url.
I know that the id is always 9 characters long and always comes after the text `track/`, but I don't know how to strip everything else.

I tried to use `this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");` to remove all the non-numeric characters, but it still leaves a variable number of other numbers, depending on the width and height of the embed frame and html color code.

Is there a simple inline way to get only a 9-digit number from a string?

The idea is that a user can just paste the embed code into a text box and it will automatically strip out everything except the song id, which is then saved in a database.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't see an answer before I did that. I thought my question was clearer without extra info.. But thank you for this answer. I will restore my question so it makes sense.

Comment: @CarySwoveland It says there are errors on the page you linked me to. "? The preceding token is not quantifiable". As an inline function triggered by onKeyUp on the text box, how would I apply it? I tried prepending 'this.value=', but it didn't work.

Comment: @CarySwoveland No, I mean in https://regex101.com/r/GzJ4ws/2, there is an error warning on the right panel about the code.

Comment: I don't see "The preceding token is not quantifiable" or any other message. Incidentally, I'm not familiar with Javascript so I'm not the one to provide the code to  extract the match. I'll be out for awhile, walkin' the dog.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Ok. Well, thank you for your answer. I think at least it is enough to help me find the exact thing I need. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucky you! You are using Javascript, one of a handful of languages whose regex engine supports variable-length positive lookbehinds. You can use the regex

```
(?<=\btracks\/.*)(?<!\d)\d{9}(?!\d)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GzJ4ws/2/).

The regex engine performs the following operations:

```
(?<=          # begin a positive lookbehind
  \btracks\/  # match the string 'tracks/' not preceded by a word char
  .*          # match 0+ characters
)             # end positive lookbehind
(?<!\d)       # negative lookbehind to match a digit 
\d{9}         # match 9 digits
(?!\d)        # negative lookahead to match a digit
```

Alternatively (and in languages that do not support variable-length positive lookbehinds), you could use

```
\btracks\/.*(?<!\d)(\d{9})(?!\d)
```

in which case the desired string of 9 digits would be held by capture group 1 (if there is a match).